# Languages with automatic casting of arbitrary large integers?

Tags: python, r, casting, julia, overflow

Out the main high-level languages used for numerical computations (e.g. R, Python, Matlab, Julia..), is there any that does the casting of arbitrary long integers to some sort of variable size type automatically instead of overflowing?

[EDIT]
I was just curious about which language could show wrong results of arithmetic operations to a user unaware of the memory limits of the different types.

This is what I have found:

#### Julia

-> You need to explicitly use a specialised structure

```
julia> 999^999
-1298546076401438441

julia> BigInt(999)^BigInt(999)
368063488259223267894700840060521865838338232037353204655959621437025609300472231530103873614505175218691345257589896391130393189447969771645832382192366076536631132001776175977932178658703660778465765811830827876982014124022948671975678131724958064427949902810498973271030787716781467419524180040734398996952930832508934116945966120176735120823151959779536852290090377452502236990839453416790640456116471139751546750048602189291028640970574762600185950226138244530187489211615864021135312077912018844630780307462205252807737757672094320692373101032517459518497524015120165166724189816766397247824175394802028228160027100623998873667435799073054618906855460488351426611310634023489044291860510352301912426608488807462312126590206830413782664554260411266378866626653755763627796569082931785645600816236891168141774993267488171702172191072731069216881668294625679492696148976999868715671440874206427212056717373099639711168901197440416590226524192782842896415414611688187391232048327738965820265934093108172054875188246591760877131657895633586576611857277011782497943522945011248430439201297015119468730712364007639373910811953430309476832453230123996750235710787086641070310288725389595138936784715274150426495416196669832679980253436807864187160054589045664027158817958549374490512399055448819148487049363674611664609890030088549591992466360050042566270348330911795487647045949301286614658650071299695652245266080672989921799342509291635330827874264789587306974472327718704306352445925996155619153783913237212716010410294999877569745287353422903443387562746452522860420416689019732913798073773281533570910205207767157128174184873357050830752777900041943256738499067821488421053870869022738698816059810579221002560882999884763252161747566893835178558961142349304466506402373556318707175710866983035313122068321102457824112014969387225476259342872866363550383840720010832906695360553556647545295849966279980830561242960013654529514995113584909050813015198928283202189194615501403435553060147713139766323195743324848047347575473228198492343231496580885057330510949058490527738662697480293583612233134502078182014347192522391449087738579081585795613547198599661273567662441490401862839817822686573112998663038868314974259766039340894024308383451039874674061160538242392803580758232755749310843694194787991556647907091849600704712003371103926967137408125713631396699343733288014254084819379380555174777020843568689927348949484201042595271932630685747613835385434424807024615161848223715989797178155169951121052285149157137697718850449708843330475301440373094611119631361702936342263219382793996895988331701890693689862459020775599439506870005130750427949747071390095256759203426671803377068109744629909769176319526837824364926844730545524646494321826241925107158040561607706364484910978348669388142016838792902926158979355432483611517588605967745393958061959024834251565197963477521095821435651996730128376734574843289089682710350244222290017891280419782767803785277960834729869249991658417000499998999
```

#### Python base

-> The variable size structure is applied automatically (I guess for any-size integer), so no risk (of course at a price)

```py
>>> 999**999
368063488259223267894700840060521865838338232037353204655959621437025609300472231530103873614505175218691345257589896391130393189447969771645832382192366076536631132001776175977932178658703660778465765811830827876982014124022948671975678131724958064427949902810498973271030787716781467419524180040734398996952930832508934116945966120176735120823151959779536852290090377452502236990839453416790640456116471139751546750048602189291028640970574762600185950226138244530187489211615864021135312077912018844630780307462205252807737757672094320692373101032517459518497524015120165166724189816766397247824175394802028228160027100623998873667435799073054618906855460488351426611310634023489044291860510352301912426608488807462312126590206830413782664554260411266378866626653755763627796569082931785645600816236891168141774993267488171702172191072731069216881668294625679492696148976999868715671440874206427212056717373099639711168901197440416590226524192782842896415414611688187391232048327738965820265934093108172054875188246591760877131657895633586576611857277011782497943522945011248430439201297015119468730712364007639373910811953430309476832453230123996750235710787086641070310288725389595138936784715274150426495416196669832679980253436807864187160054589045664027158817958549374490512399055448819148487049363674611664609890030088549591992466360050042566270348330911795487647045949301286614658650071299695652245266080672989921799342509291635330827874264789587306974472327718704306352445925996155619153783913237212716010410294999877569745287353422903443387562746452522860420416689019732913798073773281533570910205207767157128174184873357050830752777900041943256738499067821488421053870869022738698816059810579221002560882999884763252161747566893835178558961142349304466506402373556318707175710866983035313122068321102457824112014969387225476259342872866363550383840720010832906695360553556647545295849966279980830561242960013654529514995113584909050813015198928283202189194615501403435553060147713139766323195743324848047347575473228198492343231496580885057330510949058490527738662697480293583612233134502078182014347192522391449087738579081585795613547198599661273567662441490401862839817822686573112998663038868314974259766039340894024308383451039874674061160538242392803580758232755749310843694194787991556647907091849600704712003371103926967137408125713631396699343733288014254084819379380555174777020843568689927348949484201042595271932630685747613835385434424807024615161848223715989797178155169951121052285149157137697718850449708843330475301440373094611119631361702936342263219382793996895988331701890693689862459020775599439506870005130750427949747071390095256759203426671803377068109744629909769176319526837824364926844730545524646494321826241925107158040561607706364484910978348669388142016838792902926158979355432483611517588605967745393958061959024834251565197963477521095821435651996730128376734574843289089682710350244222290017891280419782767803785277960834729869249991658417000499998999
```

#### Python/Numpy

-> Same risk as in Julia:

```py
>>> v = np.array([999,999])
>>> v[0]**v[1]
-1298546076401438441
```

#### R

-> Somethign in the middle: not an error but "infinite"

```
> v = c(999,999)
> v[1]^v[2]
[1] Inf
```

Still wondering in Matlab...

Comment: Python is using `BigInt` and there is no `Int` unless you switch to `numpy` which in turn does not have `BigInt`

Comment: R has not ints so problem solved

Comment: There's the **gmp** package for R, for arbitrary large integers, and exact rational arithmetic. Julia also has **gmp** numbers (in some library - I forgot its name), and it has **BigInt** (not requiring any library).

Comment: `BigInt` is implemented using GMP library, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic.

Comment: Do you mean automatic casting of integer literals, or do you mean conversion during arithmetic operations? Julia automatically casts the literal `9223372036854775807` as `Int64`, and `9223372036854775808` as `Int128`. Julia does _not_, however, automatically promote during arithmetic operations, so `9223372036854775807 + 1` wraps around to `-9223372036854775808`.

Comment: R does have 32-bit integers, you just need to write e.g. `999L` to create one. `999L * 999L == 998001`, i.e. overflow happens too.

Answer (score 0):

Besides normal Python's integer values getting larger on demand, Numpy is also promoting from `int32` to `int64`, at least in some user-facing functions:

```py
In [4]: np.int32(2147483647), type(np.int32(2147483647))
Out[4]: (2147483647, numpy.int32)

In [5]: np.int32(2147483647) + 1, type(np.int32(2147483647) + 1)
Out[5]: (2147483648, numpy.int64)
```

But not further:

```py
In [13]: type(np.int64(np.iinfo(np.int64).max) + 1)
<ipython-input-13-e341e947aef4>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  type(np.int64(np.iinfo(np.int64).max) + 1)
Out[13]: numpy.int64

In [14]: type(np.int32(np.iinfo(np.int32).max) + 1)
Out[14]: numpy.int64
```